# how to split pdf file into multiple pdf files by specific word?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

> I have one pdf file. I want to split that file into multiple pdf files
>   by some specific word from that file. how can i do that in python ?

Comment: You've tagged this reportlab and pypdf so you've got a start. What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pdftk. It is a toolbox for working with pdf files. You can integrate it into python with the subprocess module.